# How do I disable escaping when using COPY FROM in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, csv

I have a large tab delimited file that I want to read into a table in PostgreSQL 9.5.  **It contains double-quotes and backslashes that I want to treat as regular characters.**

I think COPY FROM is the way to go, but I can't figure out how to disable escaping.

Here is a sample of the data (it's from [Google's ngram dataset](http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html)):

```
aX13_X  2006    8   5
aX13_X  2007    4   3
aX13_X  2008    2   1
a\  1852    1   1
a\  1935    1   1
a\  1937    2   2
ACT1V1T1ES  2003    15  11
ACT1V1T1ES  2004    63  6
ACT1V1T1ES  2005    1   1
ACT1V1T1ES  2006    5   4
ACT1V1T1ES  2008    4   3
ACTION="    1995    3   3
ACTION="    1996    6   5
ACTION="    1997    9   7
ACTION="    1998    19  11
ACTION="    1999    11  5
```

And the table:

```
CREATE TABLE onegram (
    id SERIAL,
    ngram character text,
    year integer NOT NULL,
    match_count integer NOT NULL,
    volume_count integer NOT NULL
);
```

If I try without modifiers, the backslash escapes the tab:

```
ngram=# copy onegram (ngram, year, match_count, volume_count)
from '/home/tims/data/ngram/test.tsv';
ERROR:  missing data for column "volume_count"
CONTEXT:  COPY onegram, line 4: "a\     1852    1       1"
```

So I switch to CSV, and then the double quote characters quote the tabs:

```
ngram=# copy onegram (ngram, year, match_count, volume_count)
from '/home/tims/data/ngram/test.tsv' WITH CSV DELIMITER E'\t';
ERROR:  unterminated CSV quoted field
CONTEXT:  COPY onegram, line 17: "ACTION="      1999    11      5
"
```

Using CSV lets me use the DELIMITER keyword.  It works if I pick a delimiter that doesn't occur in the sample (space, in this case):

```
ngram=# copy onegram (ngram, year, match_count, volume_count)
from '/home/tims/data/ngram/test.tsv' WITH CSV DELIMITER E'\t' QUOTE E' ';
COPY 16
```

But I want to be able to include any character (except for tab and newline).  **So, how can I disable QUOTE?  Or what can I use instead of COPY FROM?**

Edit: For slightly arbitrary reasons, ideally I'd like an option that does not involve pre-processing the data.

Answer (score 5):

The `copy` command by default uses `text` format with <kbd>tab</kbd> delimiter. So only one thing you need is to escape backslashes:

```
copy onegram (ngram, year, match_count, volume_count)
from program 'sed ''s/\\/\\\\/g'' < /home/tims/data/ngram/test.tsv';
select * from onegram;
╔════╤════════════╤══════╤═════════════╤══════════════╗
║ id │   ngram    │ year │ match_count │ volume_count ║
╠════╪════════════╪══════╪═════════════╪══════════════╣
║  1 │ aX13_X     │ 2006 │           8 │            5 ║
║  2 │ aX13_X     │ 2007 │           4 │            3 ║
║  3 │ aX13_X     │ 2008 │           2 │            1 ║
║  4 │ a\         │ 1852 │           1 │            1 ║
║  5 │ a\         │ 1935 │           1 │            1 ║
║  6 │ a\         │ 1937 │           2 │            2 ║
║  7 │ ACT1V1T1ES │ 2003 │          15 │           11 ║
║  8 │ ACT1V1T1ES │ 2004 │          63 │            6 ║
║  9 │ ACT1V1T1ES │ 2005 │           1 │            1 ║
║ 10 │ ACT1V1T1ES │ 2006 │           5 │            4 ║
║ 11 │ ACT1V1T1ES │ 2008 │           4 │            3 ║
║ 12 │ ACTION="   │ 1995 │           3 │            3 ║
║ 13 │ ACTION="   │ 1996 │           6 │            5 ║
║ 14 │ ACTION="   │ 1997 │           9 │            7 ║
║ 15 │ ACTION="   │ 1998 │          19 │           11 ║
║ 16 │ ACTION="   │ 1999 │          11 │            5 ║
╚════╧════════════╧══════╧═════════════╧══════════════╝
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you'll need to preprocess the data. `COPY` can't ingest this data if you want to allow any possible input. It isn't valid CSV, and it doesn't follow the rules of postgres's TSV-like native COPY format either. There is no option to set `QUOTE NONE` or something like that.

I suggest something like a perl/python script that transforms the data, which you invoke using [`COPY ... FROM PROGRAM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html). Or by piping the data into `psql` for client-side input, or by transforming the data and directly feeding it to Postgres via the client driver like `DBD::Pg` or `psycopg2`, both of which have `COPY` support.

You could always submit a postgres patch so the next person has an easier job of the same problem.

Comment: I suspect you're right.  I'll look at making a patch.

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard (famous last words?) to allow COPY to take a keyword as the quote char, like `NONE`, which is an unreserved keyword already and thus suitable for that job. You'd need to change `gram.y` to accept it. `CopyStmt` doesn't need changes, the `List` of `DefElem` there is fine. In `copy.c` you'd need to make `DoCopy` check for the `NONE` keyword in the `quote` option element; around 1084. Then actually handle that in data input.

Answer (score 0):

From **@Craig Ringer**, you should re-format the data.

Based on your data, on Linux, I used `tr` & `seq` to format CSV file before importing.

For example: suppose that `a.csv` file as below

```
aX13_X  2006    8   5
aX13_X  2007    4   3
aX13_X  2008    2   1
a\  1852    1   1
a\  1935    1   1
a\  1937    2   2
ACT1V1T1ES  2003    15  11
ACT1V1T1ES  2004    63  6
ACT1V1T1ES  2005    1   1
ACT1V1T1ES  2006    5   4
ACT1V1T1ES  2008    4   3
ACTION="    1995    3   3
ACTION="    1996    6   5
ACTION="    1997    9   7
ACTION="    1998    19  11
ACTION="    1999    11  5
```

**Format CSV, disable quote** (replace multiple spaces to one space then space & `\t` to `;`). `c.csv` is result file. However, please check your input data if it is large because I tested on small data .

```
cat a.csv | tr -s " " > b.csv;  sed -e 's/"//g' -e "s/[\t ]/;/g" b.csv  > c.csv 
cat c.csv
aX13_X;2006;8;5
aX13_X;2007;4;3
aX13_X;2008;2;1
a\;1852;1;1
a\;1935;1;1
a\;1937;2;2
ACT1V1T1ES;2003;15;11
ACT1V1T1ES;2004;63;6
ACT1V1T1ES;2005;1;1
ACT1V1T1ES;2006;5;4
ACT1V1T1ES;2008;4;3
ACTION=;1995;3;3
ACTION=;1996;6;5
ACTION=;1997;9;7
ACTION=;1998;19;11
ACTION=;1999;11;5
```

**Import to PG**

```
psql -p 5432 -d postgres -c  "copy onegram (ngram, year, match_count, volume_count) from '/opt/c.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV"
```

After importing, result likes that:

```
id |   ngram    | year | match_count | volume_count
----+------------+------+-------------+--------------
 20 | aX13_X     | 2006 |           8 |            5
 21 | aX13_X     | 2007 |           4 |            3
 22 | aX13_X     | 2008 |           2 |            1
 23 | a\         | 1852 |           1 |            1
 24 | a\         | 1935 |           1 |            1
 25 | a\         | 1937 |           2 |            2
 26 | ACT1V1T1ES | 2003 |          15 |           11
 27 | ACT1V1T1ES | 2004 |          63 |            6
 28 | ACT1V1T1ES | 2005 |           1 |            1
 29 | ACT1V1T1ES | 2006 |           5 |            4
 30 | ACT1V1T1ES | 2008 |           4 |            3
 31 | ACTION=    | 1995 |           3 |            3
 32 | ACTION=    | 1996 |           6 |            5
 33 | ACTION=    | 1997 |           9 |            7
 34 | ACTION=    | 1998 |          19 |           11
 35 | ACTION=    | 1999 |          11 |            5
```

Comment: This solution doesn't suit my problem for a few reasons.  First, the quotes are lost.  I want to keep the `ACTION="` ngram distinct from `ACTION=` ngram.  Similarly the data probably has semicolons in the ngrams.

Lastly, per my edit, I'm trying to avoid preprocessing.

Comment: I often re-format data before using `copy`. Please update your solution when you find it. Thanks.